# How can I take the result of a selection from a list and put it into another table field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections

Using Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0.2
I have 2 tables. One table populates a select list collection in  a _form view for the second table.
I need to get the result of a user selection from the select list in and enter that name value into another table field, not the id of the selection but the actual word. I would like to do this without a join table.

I have been experimenting with several tuts using books and authors and watching Ryan Bate's video tuts but none explains in detail how to solve the above. I am most confused. If I can understand the process I can recreate it in the app.

```
Author
  has_many :books
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:bookname].blank? },       :allow_destroy => true
Book
  belongs_to :author
```

Books controller examples:
    def new
      @book = Book.new
      @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
      @book = @author.books.build

```
def create
  @author = Author.find(params[:author_id])

Book _form.html.erb
<div class="tryit">
 <%= f.collection_select(:author, :author_id, @authors; :id, :name) %>
</p>
</div>
```

From here I am stuck. don't understand how to get the author name into the Book table's     authorname field. I don't want to employ join tables, just populate the book table with correct data.

Can someone please advice
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the author name

The purpose of [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) is to provide a framework for [relational database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) interactivity. Basically, these tables work with a `primary_key` (unique identifier -- typical an `id`), and a `foreign_key` (the `primary key` in another table)

Because Rails is relational *and* object-orientated, it allows you to do this:

```
@book.author.name
```

---

**Foreign Key**

When you use ActiveRecord like you're doing, it populates your tables like this:

```
authors
id | name | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at

books
id | author_id | title | ISBN | etc | created_at | updated_at
```

This means that you don't need to populate the dependent `books` table with any more data than the `foreign_key` of the `author`. This will allow Rails to call all the `author` attributes when you call a `book` object

---

**Delegate**

One way around this (if you wanted to access all the author information directly from your `book` objects`) is to use the [`delegate`][3](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method:

```
#app/models/book.rb
Class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :author
    delegate :name, to: :author, prefix: true
end
```

This will allow you to call `@book.author_name`